# Call PHP via AJAX

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

My user needs to pick an option from a first `<select>` and according to his selection, a second `<select>` should offer different options.

You may have seen this when picking a State after picking a Country in many many websites.

I know there are hundred other questions like this but I have tried lots of their answers without any success.

So, here is where I am standing right now:

```
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1" style="border:solid 1px #CCC; border-radius:4px;">Juzgado: </span>
              <select class="form-control" id="juz" name="juz">
                <option value="1">Juzgado 1</option>
                <option value="2">Juzgado 2</option>
                <option value="3">Juzgado 3</option>
              </select>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-2" id="nomDiv">
                  <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1" style="border:solid 1px #CCC; border-radius:4px;">Nominación: </span>
                  <select class="form-control" id="nom" name="id_juz_nom">

                  </select>
            </div>
```

Then... my AJAX

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('select[name=juz]').on('change', function() {

                var juz = $(this).val() 

                $.ajax({
                url: "tomarNominaciones.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: { juz.value },

                success: function (response) {

                        document.getElementById('nom').innerHTML= response;

                }
            });
          });
        });

</script>
```

And finally this is my PHP:

```
    <?php 
$juz = $_POST['juz'];
include 'conectar.php';
mysql_select_db('juz_nom');
$query  = "SELECT * FROM juz_nom WHERE juzgado=\"".$juz."\"";
$result = mysql_query($query);
?>

<span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1" style="border:solid 1px #CCC; border-radius:4px;">Nominación: </span>
<select class="form-control" id="nom" name="id_juz_nom">
<option>Seleccione Nominación</option>
<?php while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
<option value=<?php echo $row['id_juz_nom']?>><?php echo $row['nominacion']?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

I've tried many methods such as [this one](http://www.php-dev-zone.com/2013/10/country-state-city-dropdown-using-ajax.html) and [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26419691/jquery-ajax-populated-html-form-when-dropdown-selected). Without any success.

So, to be clear, **what I need to do is**: populate my second select with as many options as my MySQL query returns.

Comment: Ok so what doesnt work as it is?

Comment: `juz.value` will be undefined because `juz` is already a string. `.val()` already extracted the value.

Comment: Well.. i get no errors in my console.. but i don't get my second select populated either... it is like my JS coding is simply not there!

Comment: 4castle YOU ARE RIGHT... i can't believe it... I have been working with this for the last 4 hours... I am kissing you right now wherever you are.. thanks a lot

Comment: This is open to SQL injections. Should update your driver to `pdo` or `mysqli`. Then you can use prepared statements to stop SQL injection.

Comment: Yes chris85 you are right... although the info being posted can only be selected from a list so I shouldn't be worried.. right?

Comment: Unfortunately, not right: A malicious user could just send a post request themselves with whatever value they like.

Comment: @GonHL Nope, a request could be made direct to your PHP page, or a user could modify the DOM so it sends something else.. Never trust client side input. Also use the `@` to tag users.

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string()` can also be used to protect from sql injection. But I agree with @chris85 you should probably think about switching to a non-deprecated driver.

Comment: Oh ok, shame on me! thanks to all of you!

Comment: Also don't use mysql* functions, use mysqli/pdo, and remember to open devToolbar in your browser. also, many devs don't know they can resend ajax query through firefox/chrome devToolbar without reloading the page. (saves much time)

Comment: Stop using the **deprecated and as of PHP7 removed** mysql_* functions. Migrate to PDO and start using Prepared Statements.

Comment: Thanks a lot... Too many good advices! I am a self tought programmer so I will have to work a lot to change my ways...

Comment: I would use javascript instead of serverside model to chain selects.  Use a **JSON** file to feed each select.  Too many queries to the server.  Useless.  Think modern:  offline first,  mobile users.

Comment: Gracias amigo arriba Colombia loco!

Atte: Un chilango

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
data: { juz.value },
```

to

```
data: { juz },
```

and echo the HTML

as:

```
    echo "<span class='input-group-addon' id='basic-addon1' style='border:solid 1px #CCC; border-radius:4px;'>Nominación: </span>
    <select class='form-control' id='nom' name='id_juz_nom'>
    <option>Seleccione Nominación</option>";
 while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option value=$row['id_juz_nom']>$row['nominacion']</option>
    </select>";}
```